# How to Hot Reload flutter when running from xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-hotreload

I'm trying to do Hot Reload when running flutter code from xcode but nothing I seem to do works.

I see a console within xcode. I can see my logs there but I don't see the normal "Flutter run commands" output. When I type "r" or "R" there it just writes "r" or "R" with no change to my running app.

I have tried running `flutter run` from the terminal and I also can't type "r" or "R" without it only typing that letter into the console.

I can do do hot reload via VSCode but I'm running into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335493/could-not-run-build-ios-iphoneos-runner-app-on-try-launching-xcode-and-selecting) (I can temporarily fix this issue but it comes up every other build).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to debug my flutter code that was ran from xcode by attaching a flutter debugger.

I had to use VScode to attach the debugger. I installed the flutter extension. Second, I searched for the commend `Flutter: Attach to Flutter on Device`. Once you have that running, there are options to click to hot reload or hot restart.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/debugging

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode console doesn't work the way you're trying to do so.
Here are a few commands to Clean, Build and Run Xcode Project. Also there is no hot reload in Xcode. You can simply use these commands anywhere in Xcode except Console.

> **Shift + CMD + K** to clean.
>
> **CMD + B** to build.
>
> **CMD + R** to run.

Comment: This is a flutter-specific question. Please verify that the provided answer is for flutter projects.

Comment: (2) "You see a console within Xcode and you're writing commands in it expecting to see some output", I have answered it before, and I'll say it again, the Xcode Console doesn't work like that. You can't Hot reload flutter projects from Xcode Console either. So you're wrong again.

Comment: (3) Here are steps to run flutter builds from Mac Terminal.
First give project path like cd document/flutter/myporject whatever your project path is.
then," flutter pub get",
then, "open -a Simulator" to open a simulator if device is not connected,
then "flutter run", 

let it take its time to install pods and stuff, and once the project is running on Simulator/Device, then you can atomically see different commands on Mac terminal like press R to hot reload and etc.

Comment: Is it possible that the two of you do not agree on what exactly is meat by "hot reload flutter from/via xcode"? What could be observed in case of successfully doing that? What are the symptoms of it currently failing?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Yunnosch. I have updated my question to hopefully be more clear. I've also submitted an answer that hopefully helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that the Run Build Configuration was on Release mode so I fixed it by going to the:

**XCode > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme**

From the **Run** option go to **Info** and change **Build Configuration to Debug**

[image]